# Conversion from stationarity to non-stationarity

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, linear-systems, linear-algebra, stationary

Is there any way to convert a non-stationary signal to a stationary one, perform operations on it meant for a stationary signal and then convert it back to the non-stationary one?

Comment: differencing the series can sometimes work. that's pretty much the only one if the non-stationarity is in the mean. if the non-stationarity is only in the variance, the transformations such as log or sine can sometimes help.

Comment: What sort of signal are you dealing with?

Comment: Its a time series data for a country's GDP for about 100 years.

Comment: Best way is to partition the non-stationary signal to the duration you can assume its stationary and perform the operation you require on it. But depends on what you want to do?

Comment: I want to use the discrete Wiener estimation method of Levinson to predict the next value in the series using the available ones.

Answer (score 1):

Strict sense stationarity relates to hypothesis that the statistical law $f_{\omega(t)}$ behind the process does not change over time. Even in that case, it is difficult to access to the law from a few realizations, unless you add an ergodicity assumption (possibility to estimate sample properties from past and future data).

Strict sense non-stationarity can offer such a variety of behaviors that a stationarization is unlikely: all $f_{\omega(t)}$ should be cast to a single $f_{\omega}$. Would it exist, non-stationary processing would be a paradise, as we could apply all stationary methods.

In a lighter sense, one can consider wide-sense non-stationarity, where only the first and second moments (expectation and variance) are allowed to  vary. In [Nonstationary Models for Time Series](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/xegbohtmlnode37.html), one can explore either what is "Nonstationary in the Variance" and "Nonstationarity in the Mean".

In the mean, several  methods can be applied for deterministic trends and stochastic trends. Differentiation, parametric modeling or ARMA, ARIMA, random walk techniques can be used.

In the variance, one can look for [Variance-stabilizing transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation) (Anscombe, Box-Cox) aiming at:

> creating new values  such that the variability of the values y is not
>   related to their mean value

Comment: Thanks Laurent: Note that the ARIMA  class of models still require that a difference of some order ( which could be greater than 1 but generally 1 is common  ) be stationary ( in the mean ) and it requires stationary variance.

Comment: Nice, I will be more specific